# Can't make instance of tesseract::TessBaseAPI in c++

Tags: c++, tesseract

I installed tesseract and opencv using vcpkg on macos, everyhitng went fine.

Now i'm trying to make a simple tesseract project with cmake but:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI text_recognizer;
```

throws:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
> std::runtime_error: collate_byname::collate_byname failed to construct for

Then i changed it to:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *text_recognizer;
```

and it doesn't throw any errors, but if i try to initialize it with

```
text_recognizer = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
```

i get the same as before:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
> std::runtime_error: collate_byname::collate_byname failed to construct for

It'd be enough if someone could point me in the right direction to solve the problem!

**EDIT:**

Running cmake .. throws the warning:

```
ld: warning: direct access in function 'unsigned long 
std::__1::__str_find_first_of<char, unsigned long, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, 18446744073709551615ul>(char const*, 
unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)' from file 
'../vcpkg/installed/x64- 
osx/debug/lib/libopencv_cored.a(logtagconfigparser.cpp.o)' to global 
weak symbol 'std::__1::char_traits<char>::eq(char, char)' from file 
'CMakeFiles/startProject.dir/main.cpp.o' means the weak symbol cannot 
be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different 
translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
```

**EDIT 2**

My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set( CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/Users/alejandrocamba/Documents/screen-photo- 
to-text-quality/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" )

project(startProject)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Tesseract CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Leptonica CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(libzip REQUIRED)
find_package(libzippp CONFIG REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_executable(startProject main.cpp)

if( OpenCV_FOUND )
  # Additional Include Directories
  include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

  # Additional Library Directories
  link_directories( ${OpenCV_LIB_DIR} )

  # Additional Dependencies
  target_link_libraries(startProject ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
endif()

target_link_libraries(startProject PRIVATE leptonica)
target_link_libraries(startProject PRIVATE libtesseract)
target_link_libraries(startProject PRIVATE zip)
target_link_libraries(startProject PRIVATE libzippp::libzippp)
```

Comment: Hey, your error message seems to be cut off: `failed to construct for` - for what? In general many similar issues suggest trying to set `setlocale(LC_ALL "")`, but having a complete error message from you would help with getting a proper solution.

Comment: it doesn't say for what, that's the complete error message! frustrating... :(

Comment: A little bit more context would help then. Which OS are you using, how did you build tesseract (also did you build it on some other platform) or did you install it (say, with `brew install`)?

Comment: Can you try with this line on CMake: `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi")`

Comment: Sure! i just did, deleted the whole build folder and re ran cmake .. && make and ran the project again but i got the same error! I'm editting the question and adding my CMakeList.txt @adem

Comment: If some of the these libraries build with libstdc++ and some other build with libc++, that would cause an ABI break. Just a guess.

Comment: Thank you but i don't think that would be the case, everything works fine and compiles but at the moment the program reads a declaration of something from tesseract it throws that error. But the library links well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the answer so i started trying random things, and adding

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RELEASE")
```

Solved the issue for some reason.